# Gauge invariant supersymmetric transformations

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, supersymmetry, superspace-formalism

Given the following action
$$
\mathcal{S}=\int{d^4x\;d^2\theta\;d^2\bar{\theta}\left(\bar{Q}_+e^{2V}Q_++\bar{Q}_-e^{-2V}Q_--2\xi V\right)}+\int{d^4x\;d^2\theta\left(mQ_-Q_++\frac{\tau}{16\pi i}W^\alpha W_\alpha\right)}+h.c.
$$

Where $\bar{Q}$ is the hermitian conjugated $Q$, $\tau = \frac{\theta}{2\pi}+i\frac{4\pi}{g^2}$ the gauge coupling, $\xi$ the Fayet-Iliopoulos parameter, $W_\alpha=-\frac{1}{4}\bar{D}^2D_\alpha V$ is the gaugino superfield and $V$ the abelian vector superfield.

How can I show that the action is invariant under 
$$
Q_+\rightarrow e^{i\Lambda}Q_+ \;\\
Q_-\rightarrow e^{-i\Lambda}Q_- \;\\
V\rightarrow V-\frac{i}{2}\Lambda +\frac{i}{2}\bar{\Lambda}
$$

When I try the transformation on the first term I get the following:
$$
\bar{Q}_+e^{2V}Q_+\rightarrow \bar{Q}_+e^{2V}Q_+ e^{Im(\Lambda)}
$$
I have a similar problem with the next term

**Edit:**

$Q_+$ is a chiral superfield with charge 1

$Q_-$ is a chiral superfield with charge -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's check invariant of **first term**.
Using transformation laws and fact, that transformation are abelian:

$$Q_+\rightarrow e^{i\Lambda}Q_+ \Rightarrow \bar{Q}_+\rightarrow \bar{Q}_+ e^{-i\bar{\Lambda}}$$

$$
V\rightarrow V-\frac{i}{2}\Lambda +\frac{i}{2}\bar{\Lambda}
\Rightarrow
e^{2V}\rightarrow e^{i\bar{\Lambda}}e^{2V} e^{-i\Lambda} $$

We obtain:

$$
\bar{Q}_+ e^{2V} Q_+ \to  \bar{Q}_+ e^{-i\bar{\Lambda}} e^{i\bar{\Lambda}}e^{2V} e^{-i\Lambda} e^{i\Lambda}Q_+ = \bar{Q}_+ e^{2V} Q_+
$$

For **gauge multiplet** term:

$$
W_\alpha=-\frac{1}{4}\bar{D}^2D_\alpha V
\to
-\frac{1}{4}\bar{D}^2D_\alpha V 
-\frac{i}{8}\bar{D}^2D_\alpha\Lambda +\frac{i}{8}\bar{D}^2D_\alpha\bar{\Lambda}
$$

Now using that $\Lambda$ is chiral, $\bar{\Lambda}$ antichiral and $[\bar{D}^2,D_\alpha]=0$:
$$
D_\alpha\bar{\Lambda} =0
$$
$$
\bar{D}^2D_\alpha\Lambda = D_\alpha\bar{D}^2\Lambda = 0
$$

So $W_\alpha$ is gauge invariant quantity.

**Fayet-Iliopoulos term**:

$$
\int d^4x \;d^2\theta d^2 \bar{\theta}\; \xi V\rightarrow \int d^4x \;d^2\theta d^2 \bar{\theta}\; \xi \left(V-\frac{i}{2}\Lambda +\frac{i}{2}\bar{\Lambda}\right)
$$

Using that $\int d\theta_\alpha = D_\alpha$  and $\int d\theta_{\dot{\alpha}} = \bar{D}_{\dot{\alpha}}$ (up to the boundary term) and chirality properties,  we immediately see, that FI term is gauge invariant.

The same idea works with other terms.

Comment: Can you show this for the $W^\alpha W_\alpha$ term?

Comment: @fielder, I updated answer

Comment: thank you very much! Just a final part, how do you show that for the Fayet-Iliopoulos term ?

Comment: @fielder, I updated answer

Comment: @fielder, is my answer clear to you?